# pgfgantt: Named links in order to maintain relationship between bars

Tags: pgfgantt

I have a pretty complex pgfgantt chart. Several people are collaboratively working on it and it is subject to frequent change.

In this chart the individual `\ganttbar` items are linked with the `\ganttlink` command. The ganttbar items are referred to by *elem0*, *elem1*, ..., *elemn*.

To illustrate my problem consider this minimal pgfgantt example:

```
\begin{ganttchart}{3}{1}
\ganttbar {Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar {Task 2}{2}{3} \\
\ganttbar {Task 3}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar {Task 4}{2}{3}
\ganttlink {elem0}{elem1}
\ganttlink {elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Now lets assume that "Task 2" is removed:

```
\begin{ganttchart}{3}{1}
\ganttbar {Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar {Task 3}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar {Task 4}{2}{3}
\ganttlink {elem1}{elem2}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Of course I have to remove `\ganttlink {elem0}{elem1}`. However I also have to change all subsequent links as well in order to maintain the correct relationships. In the example above  `\ganttlink {elem2}{elem3}` had to be changed to `\ganttlink {elem1}{elem2}`. In a complex gantt chart this quickly becomes tedious and very error prone .

So my question is: Is it possible to reference a `\ganttbar` rather by a custom name than by *elemn*, e.g. `\ganttlink{mytask1}{mytask2}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option `name` to `ganttbar` allows you to change the name of the element to whatever you want.  Use this as

```
\ganttbar[name=myname]{Title}{1}{3}
```

and thereafter refer to this element as `myname`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[x unit=2cm,vgrid]{1}{4}
\ganttbar[name=t1] {Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar[name=t2] {Task 2}{2}{3} \\
\ganttbar[name=t3] {Task 3}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar[name=t4] {Task 4}{2}{3}
\ganttlink {t1}{t2}
\ganttlink {t3}{t4}
\end{ganttchart}

\medbreak

\begin{ganttchart}[x unit=2cm,vgrid]{1}{4}
\ganttbar[name=t1] {Task 1}{1}{2} \\
%\ganttbar[name=t2] {Task 2}{2}{3} \\
\ganttbar[name=t3] {Task 3}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar[name=t4] {Task 4}{2}{3}
%\ganttlink {t1}{t2}
\ganttlink {t3}{t4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```